# How to use cookies with Laravel?

Tags: php, cookies, laravel

I want to print `OK` every time user enter website except the first time.

I write that:

```
$cookie =  Cookie::get('cookie_name');
    if(!isset($cookie) || $cookie != 1) {
        Cookie::forever('cookie_name', 1);
    } else {
        echo 'OK';
    }
```

but `OK` not printed in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach the cookie to a response (Response or Redirect object) to actually set it.

Try this:

```
$cookie =  Cookie::get('cookie_name');

if(!isset($cookie) || $cookie !== 1) {
    $cookie = Cookie::forever('cookie_name', 1);
    return Response::make('Cookie Set!')->withCookie($cookie);
}

return 'OK';
```

Alternatively you can use `Cookie::queue()` to attach the cookie to the next response and avoid using `withCookie` method.